# CSS for width of asp:ListView

Tags: css, asp.net, listview

I've read that the ListView itself can't take CSS to adjust its width, but that you do it in the ItemTemplate, but I just can't get it. I'm trying to put three ListView controls side by side. Each control has an image and text to the right. Think Windows Explore file list, but only a single column with a name.

The text in each ListView will be less than 32 characters, so there should be plenty of room, but each ListView takes up more than 50% of the screen no matter what I've tried. CSS is not my strong suit.

Current CSS which is wrong

```
.lv_table{
    width:500px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.lv_tr 
{
    width: 100px;
}
.list_view 
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000000;      
}

.list_image 
{    
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;        
}

.list_item_large 
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;    
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: inline-block;  
    text-align:left;        
    min-height: 32px;      
}
```

ListView Controls

```
<table  class="lv_table">
<tr class="lv_tr"><td  class="list_view">
 <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvwCategories" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div style="width: 500px;">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>            
            <div class="list_image">
                    <img alt="" src='<%# "Styles/Images/" + Eval("category_icon") %>' height="32" width="32" />
            </div>
            <div class="list_item_large ">
                <a href='sCategories.aspx?cat_id=<%# Eval("category_id")%>'><%# Eval("Cat_title")%></a>
            </div>               
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            <div>
            </div>
        </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div>
                <img alt="" src="Styles/Images/ic_lw.png" height="48" width="48" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <b>No Categories Found</b>
            </div>               

        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td  class="list_view">
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvwLists">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div style="width: 500px;">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>            
            <div class="list_image">
                <img alt="" src='<%# "Styles/Images/" + Eval("category_icon") %>' height="32" width="32" />
            </div>
            <div class="list_item_large ">
                <a href='sCategories.aspx?cat_id=<%# Eval("category_id")%>'><%# Eval("Cat_title")%></a>
            </div>               
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            <div>
            </div>
        </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div>
                <img alt="" src="Styles/Images/ic_lw.png" height="48" width="48" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <b>No Categories Found</b>
            </div>               

        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td  class="list_view">
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvwItems">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div style="width: 500px;">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>            
            <div class="list_image">
                <img alt="" src='<%# "Styles/Images/" + Eval("category_icon") %>' height="32" width="32" />
            </div>
            <div class="list_item_large ">
                <a href='sCategories.aspx?cat_id=<%# Eval("category_id")%>'><%# Eval("Cat_title")%></a>
            </div>               
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            <div>
            </div>
        </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div>
                <img alt="" src="Styles/Images/ic_lw.png" height="48" width="48" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <b>No Categories Found</b>
            </div>               

        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: .NET Web Form controls all render out to html elements which you can apply styles to. You can also add css classes to your ListViews

Comment: Found it. I had copied the ListView template from an on-line example and didn't notice that there was an overriding CSS in the template. <div style="width: 500px;">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
            </div>

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `.lv_table` style `width` to `100%` and give your `.list_view` style a `width:33%;` and remove all the inline `width:500px;` of your `<div>`'s in your LayoutTemplates.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't see this before I commented.